# Autowiring two beans implementing same interface - how to set default bean to autowire?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, autowired

### Background:

I have a Spring 2.5/Java/Tomcat application. There is the following bean, which is used throughout the application in many places

```
public class HibernateDeviceDao implements DeviceDao
```

and the following bean which is new:

```
public class JdbcDeviceDao implements DeviceDao
```

The first bean is configured so (all beans in the package are included)

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.initech.service.dao.hibernate" />
```

The second (new) bean is configured separately

```
<bean id="jdbcDeviceDao" class="com.initech.service.dao.jdbc.JdbcDeviceDao">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="jdbcDataSource">
</bean>
```

This results (of course) in an exception when starting the server:

> nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [com.sevenp.mobile.samplemgmt.service.dao.DeviceDao] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: [deviceDao, jdbcDeviceDao]

from a class trying to autowire the bean like this

```
@Autowired
private DeviceDao hibernateDevicDao;
```

because there are two beans implementing the same interface.

### The question:

**Is it possible to configure the beans so that**

**1.** I don't have to make changes to existing classes, which already have the `HibernateDeviceDao` autowired

**2.** still being able to use the second (new) bean like this:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("jdbcDeviceDao")
```

I.e. i would need a way to configure the `HibernateDeviceDao` bean as the default bean to be autowired, simultaneously allowing the usage of a the `JdbcDeviceDao` when explicitly specifying so with the `@Qualifier` annotation.

### What I've already tried:

I tried setting the property

```
autowire-candidate="false"
```

in the bean configuration for JdbcDeviceDao:

```
<bean id="jdbcDeviceDao" class="com.initech.service.dao.jdbc.JdbcDeviceDao" autowire-candidate="false">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="jdbcDataSource"/>
</bean>
```

because the Spring documentation says that

> Indicates whether or not this bean should be considered when 
>    looking for matching candidates to satisfy another bean's 
>    autowiring requirements. **Note that this does not affect explicit 
>    references by name, which will get resolved even if the specified 
>    bean is not marked as an autowire candidate.***

which I interpreted to mean that I could still autowire `JdbcDeviceDao` using the `@Qualifier` annotation and have the `HibernateDeviceDao` as default bean. Apparently my interpretation was not correct, though, as this results in the following error message when starting the server:

> Unsatisfied dependency of type [class com.sevenp.mobile.samplemgmt.service.dao.jdbc.JdbcDeviceDao]: expected at least 1 matching bean

coming from the class where I've tried autowiring the bean with a qualifier:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("jdbcDeviceDao")
```

### Solution:

[skaffman's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21234/skaffman) [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534053/autowiring-two-beans-implementing-same-interface-how-to-set-default-bean-to-au#10534137) to try the @Resource annotation worked. So the configuration has autowire-candidate set to false for jdbcDeviceDao and when using the jdbcDeviceDao I refer to it using the @Resource annotation (instead of @Qualifier):

```
@Resource(name = "jdbcDeviceDao")
private JdbcDeviceListItemDao jdbcDeviceDao;
```

Comment: If I use this interface at 100places in the code, and I want to switch all to another implementation I don't want to change qualifier or resource annotations at all places. And I also don't want to change the code of either implementations. Why there is no explicit binding possibilities like in Guice?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

I'd suggest marking the Hibernate DAO class with [`@Primary`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html), i.e. (assuming you used `@Repository` on `HibernateDeviceDao`):

```
@Primary
@Repository
public class HibernateDeviceDao implements DeviceDao
```

This way it will be selected as the default autowire candididate, with no need to `autowire-candidate` on the other bean.

Also, rather than using `@Autowired @Qualifier`, I find it more elegant to use `@Resource` for picking specific beans, i.e.

```
@Resource(name="jdbcDeviceDao")
DeviceDao deviceDao;
```

Comment: I forgot to mention in the question that I'm using Spring 2.5 (I have now edited the question) so @Primary is not an option.

Comment: @simon: Yes, that was rather important. Try the `@Resource` annotation, as I also suggested.

Comment: Thanks, the resource annotation solved the problem - now the autowire-candidate property works as I expected.

Comment: Thanks! What's the difference between specifying the bean name via `@Resource` and `@Qualifier`, apart from the fact that the former is relatively newer than the latter?

Comment: @asgs Using resource annotation simplifies things.  Instead of having the autowired / qualifier combo, you can mark it for dependency injection and specify the name in one line.  Note that simon's solution is redundant, the autowired annotation can be removed.

Answer (score 41):

What about [`@Primary`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html)?

> Indicates that a bean should be given **preference when multiple candidates are qualified to autowire** a single-valued dependency. If exactly one 'primary' bean exists among the candidates, it will be the autowired value. This annotation is semantically equivalent to the `<bean>` element's `primary` attribute in Spring XML.

```
@Primary
public class HibernateDeviceDao implements DeviceDao
```

Or if you want your Jdbc version to be used by default:

```
<bean id="jdbcDeviceDao" primary="true" class="com.initech.service.dao.jdbc.JdbcDeviceDao">
```

`@Primary` is also great for integration testing when you can easily replace production bean with stubbed version by annotating it.

Comment: I forgot to mention in the question that I'm using Spring 2.5 (I have now edited the question) so @Primary is not an option.

Comment: @simon: I believe `primary=""` attribute was available earlier. Just declare `HibernateDeviceDao` in XML and exclude it from component/annotation scanning.

Comment: According to the documentation it's available since 3.0: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html Good tip anyhow, I'll remember the Primary annotation for the next project when I'm able to use Spring 3.x

Answer (score 9):

For Spring 2.5, there's no `@Primary`. The only way is to use `@Qualifier`.

Answer (score 4):

```
The use of @Qualifier will solve the issue.
Explained as below example : 
public interface PersonType {} // MasterInterface

@Component(value="1.2") 
public class Person implements  PersonType { //Bean implementing the interface
@Qualifier("1.2")
    public void setPerson(PersonType person) {
        this.person = person;
    }
}

@Component(value="1.5")
public class NewPerson implements  PersonType { 
@Qualifier("1.5")
    public void setNewPerson(PersonType newPerson) {
        this.newPerson = newPerson;
    }
}

Now get the application context object in any component class :

Object obj= BeanFactoryAnnotationUtils.qualifiedBeanOfType((ctx).getAutowireCapableBeanFactory(), PersonType.class, type);//type is the qualifier id

you can the object of class of which qualifier id is passed.
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why @Resource(name = "{your child class name}") works but @Autowired sometimes don't work is because of the difference of their Matching sequence

Matching sequence of @Autowire 
Type, Qualifier, Name

Matching sequence of @Resource
Name, Type, Qualifier

The more detail explanation can be found here:
[Inject and Resource and Autowired annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20450902/inject-and-resource-and-autowired-annotations)

In this case,  different child class inherited from the parent class or interface confuses @Autowire, because they are from same type; As @Resource use Name as first matching priority , it works.