# Prevent autowiring by type for certain beans in Spring

Tags: spring, autowired

In my spring context I am creating a service bean and a proxy for this service bean (explicitly). Both implement the same interface.

Can I ensure that autowiring cannot inject the target bean?

I would like to be able to use the target service with the @Resource or @Qualifier annotations, but when autowiring it should always be the proxy.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe this post could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534053/autowiring-two-beans-implementing-same-interface-how-to-set-default-bean-to-au

Comment: What does the proxy do? How do you create you application context (xml, java, annotation scanning)?

Comment: The proxy is a facade for the target bean. The context is created in xml, but with custom namespace, a custom parser, and the proxy created with a BeanFactory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Primary](http://develop.nydi.ch/2010/12/spring-primary-bean-injection/) annotation. It will indicate which bean should be use preferably when autowiring.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: There's also an XML attribute `primary="true"` if you're using XML configuration. This configuration tells Spring to always use this bean if there are multiple candidate beans for autowiring.

Answer (score 0):

You can put @Primary annotation in your proxy service like bellow:

```
@Primary
@Repository
public class ProxyOfSomeService implements SomeService
```

And after that when you use, @Autowired annotation on `SomeService` field, the `ProxyOfSomeService` will be injected by deafault.

But when you need the real service you can have it like bellow:

```
@Autowired
@Resource(name="someRealService")
private SomeService someService;
```

I think this serves your need, thanks!