# Inject and Resource and Autowired annotations

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, annotations, cdi, autowired

What's the difference between `@Inject` and `@Resource` and `@Autowired` annotations?

When should we use each of them?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-standard-annotations, http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-resource-annotation

Comment: possible duplicate of [@Resource vs @Autowired](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093504/resource-vs-autowired)

Comment: Nice explanation with examples i found is [here](http://blogs.sourceallies.com/2011/08/spring-injection-with-resource-and-autowired/)

Answer (score 129, accepted):

The difference between @Inject vs. @Autowire vs. @Resource?

**@Autowired:** spring propriety annotation (as opposed to @Inject and @Resource) that inject a resource by-type, i.e. by the class of by the interface of the annotated field or contractor. In case we have few implementation of an interface or a subclass we can narrow down the selection using the @Qualifier annotation to avoid ambiguity. For a fallback match, the bean name is considered a default qualifier value. Although you can use this convention to refer to specific beans by name, @Autowired is fundamentally about type-driven injection with optional semantic qualifiers.

**@Inject:** Annotation based on JSR-330 (Dependency Injection for Java) identifies injectable constructors, methods, and fields.  This annotation is an almost complete drop-in replacement for Spring’s @Autowired annotation. So, instead of using the Spring-specific @Autowired annotation, you might choose to use @Inject. One of the differences between @Autowired and @Inject is that @Inject does not have the required field so in case we fail to find a suitable object to inject it will fail while @Autowired can used required=false and allow null able field (only if required!).
Advantage of @Inject annotation is that rather than inject a reference directly, you could ask @Inject to inject a Provider. The Provider interface enables, among other things, lazy injection of bean references and injection of multiple instances of a bean. 
In case we have few implementation of an interface or a subclass we can narrow down the selection using the @Named annotation to avoid ambiguity.  @Named annotation works much like Spring’s @Qualifier

**@Resource:** annotation based on JSR-250. @Resource is quite similar to @Autowired and @Inject, but the main difference is the execution paths taken to find out the required bean to inject.  @Resource will narrow down the search first by name then by type and finally by Qualifiers (ignored if match is found by name). @Autowired and @Inject will narrow down the search first by type then by qualifier and finally by the name.

Comment: Can you say something about what is recommended? Best practice?

Comment: I would be happy to response on your comment, but I prefer to keep this answer as is. Would you post a new question.

Comment: In last line, you have mentioned @Autowired also search by name, as I know It doesn't have name option, does it ?

Comment: See my update to the @Autowired  description. from the docs http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html "For a fallback match, the bean name is considered a default qualifier value."

Comment: @Jan-TerjeSørensen I would advice use framework independent `@Inject` annotation everywhere. Cause of if you decide to change Spring to e.g. Google Guice (or any another JSR-330 DI framework) you wouldn't  change you code.

Answer (score 21):

```
|------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|-----------------------|
|            | Setter/Field  | Constructor   | Applicable to | Matching order        |
|            | injection     | injection     | type          |                       |
|------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|-----------------------|
| @Autowired |       X       |       X       |               | Type, Qualifier, Name |
|------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|-----------------------|
| @Inject    |       X       |       X       |               | Type, Qualifier, Name |
|------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|-----------------------|
| @Resource  |       X       |               |       X       | Name, Type, Qualifier |
|------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|-----------------------|
```

So in Spring dependency injection `@Inject` and `@Autowired` have exactly the same behaviour.

Comment: What does "applicable to type" column signifies in the table?

Comment: @RBz See: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/Resource.html
"If the annotation is applied to the component class, the annotation declares a resource that the application will look up at runtime." But I'm not sure if this would also work with Spring DI.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Haim answer [there is good description](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-standard-annotations) of the difference between Spring and JSR-330 (Dependency Injection for Java) annotations and how to use the last with Spring.