# Spring FactoryBean and autowiring not working : expected single matching bean but found 2

Tags: java, spring, annotations, factory, autowired

I have two classes, each one autowiring the same class through a factory :

```
@Service
public class AnalyseDispensationNominativeMetierService implements IAnalyseDispensationNominativeMetierService {

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("interfaceAutomateServiceFactory")
  private IInterfaceAutomateMetierService interfaceAutomateMetierService;
  [...]


@Service
public class AnalysePreparationGlobaleMetierService implements IAnalysePreparationGlobaleMetierService {

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("interfaceAutomateServiceFactory")
  private IInterfaceAutomateMetierService interfaceAutomateMetierService;
  [...]
```

---

The object I want to create through the factory :

```
@Service
public class InterfaceAutomate implements IInterfaceAutomateMetierService {
[...]
```

---

The factory :

```
@Service("interfaceAutomateServiceFactory")
public class InterfaceAutomateServiceFactory implements FactoryBean<IInterfaceAutomateMetierService> {

  @Autowired(required = true)
  private InterfaceAutomate ijinInterfaceAutomate;

  @Override
  public IInterfaceAutomateMetierService getObject() {
    return ijinInterfaceAutomate;
  }

  @Override
  public Class<?> getObjectType() {
    return IInterfaceAutomateMetierService.class;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isSingleton() {
    return false;
  }
```

---

I keep getting the following error, even though I'm using qualifier annotation... Any idea on what I'm doing wrong ? :

```
No unique bean of type [IInterfaceAutomateMetierService] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: [interfaceAutomate, interfaceAutomateServiceFactory]
```

---

Complete stack trace

```
GRAVE: Exception lors de l'envoi de l'évènement contexte initialisé (context initialized) à l'instance de classe d'écoute (listener) org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'analysePreparationGlobaleMetierService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private dispensation.commun.service.metier.IInterfaceAutomateMetierService dispensation.analysePreparationGlobale.service.metier.impl.AnalysePreparationGlobaleMetierService.interfaceAutomateMetierService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [dispensation.commun.service.metier.IInterfaceAutomateMetierService] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: [interfaceAutomate, interfaceAutomateServiceFactory]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:925)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:472)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:388)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:293)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5226)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5221)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private dispensation.commun.service.metier.IInterfaceAutomateMetierService dispensation.analysePreparationGlobale.service.metier.impl.AnalysePreparationGlobaleMetierService.interfaceAutomateMetierService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [dispensation.commun.service.metier.IInterfaceAutomateMetierService] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: [interfaceAutomate, interfaceAutomateServiceFactory]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [dispensation.commun.service.metier.IInterfaceAutomateMetierService] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: [interfaceAutomate, interfaceAutomateServiceFactory]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:823)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:730)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:485)
    ... 22 more
```

Comment: Why are you doing this: `@Autowired(required = true) private InterfaceAutomate ijinInterfaceAutomate;`? Using the FactoryBean and the `@Service` annotation on `InterfaceAutomate` is kind of redundant.

Comment: @user3145373ツ The config is done through annotation    
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="[...]/>

Comment: Why do you need `InterfaceAutomateServiceFactory` class?

Comment: @AndreiStefan : I didnt write the code, I'm just trying to make it work...

Comment: (But I think at some point the factory will be used to switch between two different implementations)

Comment: Can you post the complete stack trace?

Comment: @AndreiStefan : I just added it to my post

Comment: Please, see my updated answer below.

Comment: Which Spring version are you using? Which `Qualifier` annotation are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end, I solved my problem by changing the name of the factoryBean to match the name of the injected field, and by removing one entry in the scanning of the project. (Could it be that the "double scanning" was causing trouble ?)

```
<context:component-scan base-package="dispensation.**.factory.**,dispensation.**.metier.factory.**
```

=>

```
<context:component-scan base-package="dispensation.**.factory.**
```

---

```
@Service("interfaceAutomateMetierService")
public class InterfaceAutomateServiceFactory implements FactoryBean<IInterfaceAutomateMetierService> {
```

---

```
@Service
public class AnalysePreparationGlobaleMetierService implements IAnalysePreparationGlobaleMetierService {

  @Autowired
  private IInterfaceAutomateMetierService interfaceAutomateMetierService;
```

Comment: I had the same exception due to a double scanning as well.

Comment: I had the same exception and solved it just by changing the name of the factoryBean. I suspect it conflicts with the default implementation of the component's constructor (empty constructor).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("interfaceAutomateServiceFactory")
private IInterfaceAutomateMetierService interfaceAutomateMetierService;
```

try this

```
@Resource(name="interfaceAutomateServiceFactory")
private IInterfaceAutomateMetierService interfaceAutomateMetierService;
```

Answer (score 2):

Using @Primary annotation with your bean(one of them from the two) can solve the issue.The Question however still remains as to why the @Resource annotation for Spring is unable  to distinguish based on Autowiring.

Reference "[Autowiring two beans implementing same interface - how to set default bean to autowire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534053/autowiring-two-beans-implementing-same-interface-how-to-set-default-bean-to-au)"

Answer (score 0):

If you can't or don't want to modify the source code, exclude the apparently redundant factory bean by adding an <exclude-filter /> to <context:component-scan />. Also <context:annotation-config /> is implied through <context:component-scan /> by default.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why @Resource(name = "{your child class name}") works but @Autowired sometimes don't work is because of the difference of their Matching sequence

Matching sequence of @**Autowire**: 
Type, Qualifier, Name

Matching sequence of @**Resource**:
Name, Type, Qualifier

The more detail explanation can be found here:
[Inject and Resource and Autowired annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20450902/inject-and-resource-and-autowired-annotations)

In this case,  different child class inherited from the parent class or interface confuses @Autowire, because they are from same type;

On the other hand, @Resource use Name as first matching priority , it works.