# How Can I Override an Autowired Spring Bean With an External/3rd Party Bean

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I have a situation where I want to enable clients to inject their own bean implementing a common interface into my class but otherwise use a default bean.

As an example:

```
public class TestClass {

    // Clients can inject this, otherwise use a default...
    @Autowired
    private ConfigInjector configInjector; 

}
```

My defined interface and default implementation:

```
public interface ConfigInjector {
    String getConfig();
}

@Component
public class DefaultConfigInjector implements ConfigInjector {
    public String getConfig() {
        return "DEFAULT CONFIG"
    } 
}
```

An external client wants to inject this implementation of my ConfigInjector interface:

```
@Component
public class ExternalConfigInjector implements ConfigInjector {
    public String getConfig() {
        return "EXTERNAL CONFIG"
    } 
}
```

Using @Autowired in TestClass, if the client attempts to use TestClass with his own ConfigInjector implementation (ExternalConfigInjector),  then more than one ConfigInjector implementation will exist, resulting in a **NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException** exception.

So, how can I share my TestClass with clients allowing them to use their own ConfigInjector to override my default?

Answer (score 1):

1. you may use @ConditionalOnProperty annotation
2. according to the name of the variable/argument
3. using the @primary annotation
4. using @Qualifier annotation

a recommended free course (1.5 h)
name "Spring Framework And Dependency Injection For Beginners" at www.udemy.com
explains all main issues and use cases.

Comment: The Primary annotation worked.  My question is in fact similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534053/autowiring-two-beans-implementing-same-interface-how-to-set-default-bean-to-au?rq=1) which also suggests using the Primary annotation.  Thanks!

Comment: welcome, really recommend watching the short course :-)