# Bean with different id but same class is not getting alias

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, alias

I have two beans `indCartStrategy` and `usCartStrategy`, with different id but the same class and different parameter values. I am aliasing both of them to the same alias. Instead of calling my later alias id it is still calling the former bean, not the one that I have declared.

```
    <alias name="indCartStrategy" alias="cartStrategy"/>
<bean id="indCartStrategy" parent="defaultCartStrategy" class="com.strategy.impl.USCartStrategyImpl">
    <property name="cartValidators">
        <map key-type="com.validation.USCartValidationType">
            <entry key="CART_PAGE">
                <list value-type="com.validation.USCartValidator">
                    <bean class="com.validation.impl.USValidator2"/>
                </list>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>





<alias name="usCartStrategy" alias="cartStrategy"/>
<bean id="usCartStrategy" parent="defaultCartStrategy" class="com.strategy.impl.USCartStrategyImpl">
    <property name="cartValidators">
        <map key-type="com.validation.USCartValidationType">
            <entry key="CART_PAGE">
                <list value-type="com.validation.USCartValidator">
                    <bean class="com.validation.impl.USValidator1"/>
                    <bean class="com.validation.impl.USValidator2"/>
                </list>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

In my bean i.e. `indCartStrategy` `USValidator1` is not getting called still when I am calling cartStrategy both the validators i.e. `USValidator1` and `USValidator2` are getting called.

Comment: Any specific reason why you're trying to have the same alias for different beans? If the purpose is to have two implementations of the same base interface, maybe you can use different "name" attributes for each bean, and use the @Qualifier attribute to choose the required implementation inside anigher bean.

Comment: @Daud : The original usCartStrategy cannot be modified as it from an API so I can only change my implementation i.e. indCartStrategy

Comment: Maybe this would be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534053/autowiring-two-beans-implementing-same-interface-how-to-set-default-bean-to-au (no need to use @Primary)