# Spring Boot - Override bean from controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, javabeans, spring-bean

1. I have two controllers (**ControllerA** and **ControllerB**)
2. Both controllers call to a service (**MyService**).
3. **MyService** calls to an interface called **MyRepository** which has two implementations (**FirstRepository** and **SecondRepository**).

How is possible to use **FirstRepository** when the service (**MyService**) is called from **ControllerA** and use **SecondRepository** when the call comes from **ControllerB**?

This way I can reuse **MyService** and which repository is used comes from Spring Configuration.

Comment: Conceptionally you have two services, not one. Have a base (possibly abstract) class MyService and two subclasses MyService1 and MyService2 which autowire FirstRepository and SecondRepository respectively. And these services are autowired into ControllerA and B respectively.

Answer (score 1):

I can see two possible solutions here.
 1. In you MyService class autowire both implementations with `@Qualifier` annotation (you can also autowire List.
Then MyService method would have a parameter saying which MyRepository implementation should be called. I would not recommend this solution.
 2. Define two implementations of MyService (FirstService, SecondService). Then FirstService would autowire FirstRepository and SecondService would autowire SecondRepository (use `@Qualifier annotation again`. Now you can easily inject FirstService to ControllerA and SecondService to ControllerB.

But first I would think about architecture. Maybe you don't need separate controllers?

Comment: Thanks @standy, you gave me the idea!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked [@Primary](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html) or [@Resource](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-annotations-resource-inject-autowire) or [@Qualifier](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-qualifier-annotation) annotations? Based on your requirement you can choose out of them.

Something similar has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534053/autowiring-two-beans-implementing-same-interface-how-to-set-default-bean-to-au).

Comment: Checked those annotations but don't apply to my use case :-/

Comment: I am confused with the answer, you are trying to map two controllers on same api URL ?

Comment: Inside each controller there is a method with distinct `/path` but was not included to keep the example short. Maybe I should add it..

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating two controllers and defining two `@Configuration` classes, one for each `@Controller`.

And using the `@Qualifier` annotations defined two sets of beans, and then in each controller let Spring know which `@Qualified` bean I want injected.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/inapp/purchases")
class AController(
  @Qualifier("appStore") private val redeemPurchaseService: RedeemPurchaseService
) : RedeemPurchaseApiDocumentation { // More code }
```

And the other controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/inapp/purchases")
class GPlayRedeemPurchaseController(
  @Qualifier("gplay") private val redeemPurchaseService: RedeemPurchaseService
) : RedeemPurchaseApiDocumentation { // More code }
```

And two `@Configuration` files, one per controller.