# Java Spring How to mock beans which implements the same interface

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, spring-test

I've a bean which is created as follow

```
@Profile({"test", "dev", "int"})
@Bean
public CustomerEmailSenderImpl customerEmailSenderImpl(){
    return new CustomerEmailSenderImpl ();
}
```

And in a test class, I mock the class as follow:

```
   @ActiveProfiles(profiles = {"test"})
   .....
    @MockBean
    private CustomerEmailSenderImpl customerEmailSenderImpl;
```

Now. I have to create a second email class which must be used specifically when with profile "test". So I created an Interface (CustomerEmailSender) which both classes implement. And the bean creation is done as follow.

```
@Profile({"dev", "int"})
@Bean(name = "customerEmailSender")
public CustomerEmailSender customerEmailSenderImpl1(){
    return new CustomerEmailSenderImpl1 ();
}

@Profile({"test"})
@Bean(name = "customerEmailSender")
public CustomerEmailSender customerEmailSenderImpl2(){
    return new CustomerEmailSenderImpl2 ();
}
```

The Mock I changed a follow

```
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = {"test"})
...
@MockBean
private CustomerEmailSender customerEmailSender;
```

The application starts without errors.
But the test doesn't mock the bean CustomerEmailSenderImpl2. The bean is always instantiated, and the real code is executed.
Even changing from Interface to Class-name in the test class didn't help:

```
@MockBean
private CustomerEmailSenderImpl2 customerEmailSenderImpl2;
```

What is needed to have the bean CustomerEmailSenderImpl2 mocked ?

Comment: this might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534053/autowiring-two-beans-implementing-same-interface-how-to-set-default-bean-to-au

Comment: It's all about mocking the class.  Otherwise all works fine.

Comment: in that case, your title has nothing to do with your question. Do you know how to use a mocking framework? personally I mostly use Mockito

Comment: I don't see how you expect a mock to be returned if you `return new CustomerEmailSenderImpl2 ()` in the config.

Comment: I've updated the title which summarizes better the issue

Comment: When the Mock works, Spring doesn't instantiate the bean , and thus doesn't use the code in the config class.

Comment: We're going to need an [mcve]. So many possibilities and combinations of annotations to both spring and junit.

Comment: do you have `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` before your test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use @Qualifier, and then to use the qualifier name as variable name in the test class.

```
@Profile({"test"})
@Bean(name = "customerEmailSender")
@Qualifier(value="customerEmailSenderImpl2")
public CustomerEmailSender customerEmailSenderImpl2(){
    return new CustomerEmailSenderImpl2 ();
}



@MockBean
private CustomerEmailSender customerEmailSenderImpl2;
```