# Multiple rest templates in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

I want to configure multiple rest template clients to access different API's. Both are having different authorization headers. I already configured one, Same way configured other rest template too, but that throws error `bean 'restTemplate' defined in class path resource .class could not be registered.`.

```
@Configuration
public class RestTemplateConfig {


    @Autowired
    private HeaderRequestInterceptor headerRequestInterceptor;

    //constructor
    public RestClientConfig() {}

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate( RestTemplateBuilder builder ) {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = builder.build();
        restTemplate.setInterceptors(Collections.singletonList(headerRequestInterceptor));
        return restTemplate;
    }

}
```

HeaderRequestInterceptor has base64 encoded authorization, so could not post that code here.

Another RestTemplate:

```
@Configuration
public class AnotherRestClientConfig {


    @Autowired
    private AnotherHeaderRequestInterceptor anotherHeaderRequestInterceptor;

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate( RestTemplateBuilder builder ) {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = builder.build();
        restTemplate.setInterceptors(Collections.singletonList(anotherHeaderRequestInterceptor));
        return restTemplate;
    }
}
```

Could someone let me know how to configure multiple rest templates in an application.

Comment: You could use a qualifier https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447877/how-does-spring-autowire-by-name-when-more-than-one-matching-bean-is-found

Comment: yeah, got it. annotated 2 rest templates with named @Bean(name="")  & autowired them using @Qualifier.

Comment: Couldn't you use a single rest template and interceptor, and conditionally add the different auth header according to the request?

Answer (score 2):

you could use `@Qualifier` as mentioned by @VirtualTroll. Or create a specific client bean per api and hold the restemplate instance there.

```
@Component
public class ApiClient1 {

    private final RestTemplate customRestTemplate;

    public ApiClient1() {
        this.customRestTemplate = ...
    }

    public void useApi() {
    }
}
```